# How to prevent direct access to deployed API services exposed by nginx ingress controller

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kops, nginx-ingress

I've deployed an application on aws using kops and ingress nginx controller.

From what I’ve understood it looks like ingress controller allows to expose each services deployed in the cluster publicly. So it makes me wonder about security and authentication.

What is the architecture of my project ?
I got 3 services deployed in a cluster:

1. -client-ui (front-end)
2. -authentication-api (creates/generates/verifies JWT token and call other services like data-api)
3. -data-api (an API that create/read/update/delete sensitive data in the DB)

So the question is: if Ingress controller exposes all services, how do you restrict access to specific service, if the user is not allowed to ?

In this case data-api should only be accessible from authentication-api. So if in my browser I type
www.client-ui.com/data/getXXX obviously I should not be be able to access that endpoint. I should only be able to do it from authentication-api if his jwt token has been verified.

So I guess some apis should be accessible only from within the cluster and some publicly !?

Could you please explain how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the cloud provider, there are different annotations on the ingress services for that. What you want is an internal load balancer for a specific ingress resource.
In your case (AWS) this should be:

`annotations:
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"`

See:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/
- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/c3ce6b892e5f1cc1066f81c19482dded2901ad45/docs/user-guide/multiple-ingress.md

Comment: Deploying an ingress controller doesn't automatically expose all Services; just the ones for which you create an Ingress. So I could create ingress for my client and the authentication API, and a clusterIP service for the data-api as clusterIP is only accessible internally ?

Comment: What your ingress definition does is: it configures your ingress controller pod. The ingress controller pod is in your case an nginx application. This pod needs a load balancer to be available from external networks.
Between your ingress controller pod and this service you have a 1:1 relationship.
If you want to have different kinds of accessablity you usually deploy multiple ingress controller with different types (ingress classes). In your ingress definitions you than specify this ingress class (internal/external/etc.)